# How to run windows headless server inside a docker container?

Tags: python, windows, docker

Suppose I got a `main.py` script that makes use of chrome, and it mainly depends of `pyautogui` and `tkinter` libraries (GUI libraries).

Is it possible to run a headless windows virtual machine inside a docker container that heavily depends on GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Nano-Server from Microsoft to run Windows Headless on a docker container

[Nano Server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-nanoserver)

My suggestion would be using an Ubuntu or an Alpine Linux image as an alternative since it's being used to run a python script.